# How do I create a JScrollPane within a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtabbedpane, jviewport

I am trying to create a JScrollPane within one of the tabs to my JTabbedPane. I tried what I though would work which was this:

```
    pane.add("Main", mainGame);// These are my other tabs
    pane.add("Upgrades", upgradeScreen); //the JTabbedPane
    pane.add("Credits", creditsTab);
    upgradeScreen.setLayout(null); //The null layout
    lblMoney2.setBounds(10, 11, 277, 22);
    upgradeScreen.add(lblMoney2); // A simple JLabel
    scrollPane.add(upgradeScreen); //my JScrollPane
```

Where pane is my JTabbedPane and scrollPane is my JScrollPane. This simply got rid of my upgradesScreen tab. I kind of expected this but I did not know what else to do. If more code is needed for you to figure it out, tell me and i'll put it in, otherwise, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Don't us `JScrollPane#add`, instead you want to use [`JScrollPane#setViewportView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29)

Check out [How to use ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) more details.

Advise- Don't use `null` layouts, they limit the ability for your application to run on multiple platforms. Instead take the time to learn how layout managers work

Comment: @sage Yeah, but you got the double parent issue first, so +1 to you ;)

Comment: The other day of `JTextArea` from one of your answer, i did dig it's source and found that text area view never use `\r\n` for new line, so actually your experience was correct :). in fact, i do think that i lack in experience. that is why sometimes my answer become complete wrong. yesterday while answering a question try-finally returning order, i knew the correct returning order but still i made it complete wrong by writing the reverse order. :(

Answer (score 2):

> This simply got rid of my upgradesScreen tab.'

yes, because no component can have two parents at once. You added `upgradeScreen` to `JTabbedPane` first and then again added it to a `JScrollPane`. The Component's add(component) function will eventually call the `addImpl(component)` function: which will remove the component from it's old parent and add it to the new parent.

**However:**

1. You need to add the `JScrollPane` to the `JTabbedPane` instance.
2. The component which you wish to scroll set it as a view to `JScrollPane` using the `setViewportView(component)` function. *for your context it is the `upgradeScreen`*